# to save/hold/keep a place/spot

Tags: difference, verbs

Is there any difference in meaning between "to save/hold/keep a place/spot"? Are they equally usual in US and UK?

Can all of them be used with either the prepositional complement "for somebody" or an indirect object (somebody)? The constructions "hold somebody a place/spot" and "keep somebody a place/spot" sound odd to me, but I would like to hear from English native speakers.

Example:

- Save a place for me. Save me a place.
- Save a spot for me. Save me a spot.
- Hold a place for me. Hold me a place.
- Hold a spot for me. Hold me a spot.
- Keep a place for me. Keep me a place.
- Keep a spot for me. Keep me a spot.

Answer (score 1):

Every one of your twelve example sentences are nearly 100% interchangeable for the purposes you are asking about. Off the top of my head, I can't think of any detailed example when they wouldn't be.

As a native speaker, I use any of these interchangeably all the time and *I won't remember which I use because they mean the same thing.*

The only reason I might use one rather than the other would be due to [connotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connotation), but even then I wouldn't think about it. Choosing one rather than the other, as a native speaker, would be pure instinct.

That's my take. It's pure preference and opinion and every option is correct.